# Discovering hosts in a different subnet

Tags: lan

There is an OpenWRT router with two interfaces: `br0` and `wlan0`:

- br0: 192.168.129.0/24
- wlan0: 192.168.130.0/24

`br0` is in firewall zone `lan` and `wlan0` is in firewall zone `alien`.

I have configured zone `lan` and `alien` that they can talk to each other.

Now hosts connected to `br0` and `wlan0` can successfully ping/ssh to each other, which is fine. For example, 192.168.129.200 can ping/ssh 192.168.130.200, vice versa.

My question is, is there a way to make hosts in one subnet to "discover" hosts in another one? For example, in LAN games like Counter-Striker, laptops in different subnets can discover each other without specifying IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on the method of discovery. In the very probable case that these programs use link-local broadcast (for instance, sending messages to `255.255.255.255`), then there is no way to make it work (no good, standards-compliant way, at least), because such broadcasts are defined to be link-local. What you *could* do is to bridge the links into one, virtual link using a single subnet, but that doesn't seem to be what you want, since you put them into different firewall zones.

If the programs use IP multicast, on the other hand, there may well be ways to deal with it, but I can't say I'm familiar enough with multicast to advice on the concrete procedure, and I very much doubt that they actually use multicast to begin with.

In the unlikely case that they use mDNS, the simplest way to fix your problem would probably be to set up `avahi-daemon` on the router to bridge the subnets for the purpose of mDNS.